# Regex for matching a string with any capitalization except for a specific capitalization

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to construct a regex to match a string in any capitalization except for a specific capitalization. For example, given `foobar`, I would like to match `Foobar`, `fooBar`, `FOOBAR`, etc., but not `foobar`.

A workaround which has the desired result is to replace all `foobar` (case sensitive) by a different string, say `ABC`, and then do a case-insensitive search for `foobar` -- then it will match all the variants. But I'd rather have a way to do it without modifying the text to be searched.

I'm working with Vim, but if anyone knows a way to do this is any regex flavor, I'm sure I could figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

For flavors that supports modifying the regex flags, one can use the following:

```
(?!foobar)(?i)foobar
```

That uses a negative case sensitive lookahead, and then swaps to incase-sensitive mode, to match the string again.

Vim does not support toggling ignorecase midway though a match, as `\c` and `\C` will apply for the whole match.

FWIW then you can do something as stupid as:

```
/\C\(foobar\)\@![fF][oO][oO][bB][aA][rR]
```